# How to access element inside a nested iframe in cypress with src attribute and no id?

Tags: iframe, cypress

I have to access an element which is inside 4th iframe of 4 nested Iframes. Parent Iframes have ids but this has src. How do I find that element?
I'm able to access the 3 Iframes with ids but the 4th one which has src is not accessible. I'm not sure if the code I wrote(line#4/5) are correct.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
And ('I complete the question', () => {
cy.wait(3000);
 
cy.get('#Iframe1').its('0.contentDocument').its('body') //iframe1
.find('#Iframe2').its('0.contentDocument').its('body') //iframe2 which is inside iframe1
 .find('#Iframe3').its('0.contentDocument').its('body') //iframe3 which is inside iframe2
 .find('Iframe'[src="google.com"]'').its('0.contentDocument').its('body') //iframe4 which is     inside iframe3
.find(.Input1).type('Answer1');
 });


And ('I complete the question', () => {
cy.wait(3000);
  cy.get('#Iframe1').its('0.contentDocument').its('body') //iframe1
  .find('#Iframe2').its('0.contentDocument').its('body') //iframe2
  .find('#Iframe3').its('0.contentDocument').its('body')  //iframe3
.within(() => {
  cy.get('[@src="url"]').its('0.contentDocument').its('body') //iframe4 getting the src 
.find(.Input1).type('Answer1');
   });
 });
```